# USE Open XML to extract the CDATA

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-openxml

I have xml which has the data embedded in CDATA. I would like to extract the info in different fields. But not able to do it.

```
<Item_Response Format="text/xml">   
<![CDATA[ <Item sequence="1" type="item" itemId="999999" 
itemVersion="2012-04-07T13:43:27">
<response><bubbleinput answered="y" input_id="bubbleinput1">
<bubble id="bubble1"/>
</bubbleinput></response></Item> ]]>
</Item_Response>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract CDATA value with XPath. Then use openxml on extracted value.

```
declare @xml xml = '<Item_Response Format="text/xml"><![CDATA[ <Item sequence="1" type="item" itemId="999999" itemVersion="2012-04-07T13:43:27"><response><bubbleinput answered="y" input_id="bubbleinput1"><bubble id="bubble1"/></bubbleinput></response></Item> ]]></Item_Response>'

-- openxml
declare
    @idoc int,
    @qxml xml = cast(@xml.value('(/Item_Response)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as xml)

exec sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc output, @qxml

select
    *
from
    openxml(@idoc, '/Item', 0) with (
        sequence int '@sequence',
        bubbleinput nvarchar(1) './response/bubbleinput/@answered'
    ) as XMLData

exec sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
```